# What should happen if no one answers your bounty question

Tags: discussion, bounty

I've never seen it happen before until recently.  What should happen if you post a bounty on your question and no one answers after 7 days.  I think you should get your bounty back but I'm biased :)

I would like to see what others think.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3434/we-penalise-people-for-asking-questions-nobody-else-is-interested-in-is-this-int

Answer (score 2):

This is answered on Meta.stackoverflow.com: [What happens if there are no answers to a bounty question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9902/what-happens-if-there-are-no-answers-to-a-bounty-question)

Answer (score 2):

this is covered in

https://money.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty

> In any case, you will *always* give up the amount of reputation specified in the bounty, so if you start a bounty, be sure to follow up and award your bounty to the best answer!

Comment: Thanks for answering Jeff.  I agree that it is covered in the FAQ.  I just think it's a little messed up that I loose my rep and get NOTHING.  I don't expect y'all to change your rules for me.  I was just hoping to get some different perspectives on the topic.  I don't think I phrased my question properly since people seem to be answering the question "What happens" instead of answering the question "What should happen".

Comment: @wcm - Not forcing the rep reduction on the user offering the unrewarded bounty would open the door for bounty being abused to gain attention for any/all questions.